# LESS Recursive Loop: No Matching Definitions Found

Tags: loops, recursion, less

I have a mixin I'm creating for generating grids in LESS:

```
/*Grid*/
@num-cols: 12;
@rowWidth: 100%;
@container-lateral-padding: 1em;
@col-margin-right: 3.8%;
@col-unit: (@rowWidth + @col-margin-right) / @num-cols;
@col-identifier: "col";
@col-identifier-nums: false;
@col-identifier-names: true;

@column-selector-number-at-end: false;
@column-selector-number-at-beginning: true;

.setGrid(@index) when (@index > 1), (@column-selector-number-at-end == false) {
    (~".@{index}-@{colNotation}") {
        width: @col-unit * @index - @col-margin-right;
    }
    .setGrid(@index - 1);
}
.setGrid(0) {}
.setGrid(@num-cols);
```

But I will get the error:

> No matching definition was found for `.setGrid()`

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is right here: `when (@index > 1)`. You don't have a case for when the value is `1` (hence the "No matching definition" error). So you need `when (@index >= 1)`.